# Select all rows based on a condition present in a single row

Tags: sql, impala

Given a table that looks like this:

| id | year_month | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022_01 | 9 |
| 1 | 2022_02 | 5 |
| 1 | 2022_03 | 4 |
| 2 | 2022_01 | 11 |
| 2 | 2022_02 | 13 |
| 2 | 2022_03 | 10 |
| 3 | 2022_01 | 3 |
| 3 | 2022_02 | 15 |
| 3 | 2022_03 | 4 |

A query is needed that extracts all rows with the same id if any of those rows have a count value >= 10.

The expected result would look like this:

| id | year_month | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022_01 | 11 |
| 2 | 2022_02 | 13 |
| 2 | 2022_03 | 10 |
| 3 | 2022_01 | 3 |
| 3 | 2022_02 | 15 |
| 3 | 2022_03 | 4 |

So basically it will select all rows with id 2 because all counts are >= 10, but it will also select all rows with id 3 because the entry for 2022_02 has a count higher than 10.

A simple `SELECT * FROM table WHERE count >= 10` doesn't do the job of course.

I'm not even sure how to search for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as (
select id from table_a group by id having max(count) > 10)
select t.id,
       t.year_month,
       t.count
  from table_a t
  join cte
 using (id);
```